# Flutter checkbox class: When I tick a card, all the others are getting selected too

Tags: dart, flutter

```
  bool selected = false;

   new Card(
          shape: selected
              ? new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))
              : new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),

          child: new Row(


              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[



            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text("${ticketGroups[i]['ticket_name']}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins')),
            ),
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text(ticketGroups[i]["used"].toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0, fontFamily: 'Poppins')),
            ),

            new Checkbox(
                value: selected,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selected = !selected;
                  });

                })
```

[image: When I select one card, the following gets selected too]

I would like to be able to tick only a single card, however all the cards are getting ticked as soon as I tick any one.
Also the cards are created dynamically, would be this the issue caused?

Comment: You need a distinct `selected` value for every row. It's not clear from your code how you handle that.

Comment: How can I do a distinct selected value for every row?, All the functions the implements the selection are listed above, it is literally it.

Comment: Please add the code that shows how you create the rows. It's a bit difficult from the code you provided. You could also remove all layout related code to make it easier to see what the intention of the code is. Layout is not related to the problem at hand anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an index for each card / list item as Günter says in his comment. The best option Ive seen so far is using list view with itemBuilder, something like this:

```
return new ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => new Card(
      shape: selected[index]
          ? new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))
          : new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
          ...
  itemCount: selected.length, // Tell itemBuilder how many items the list has
  ... // Rest of your code...
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give each checkbox it's own identity. When you dynamically create them call them selected1, selected2, etc..